# ¿Cómo llamar variables de diferente tipo de una clase a otra en TypeScript?

Tags: typescript

Está es la clase que contiene las variables:

```
export class RequestVO {

    public requestCode: number;
    public comercialStructureCode: string;
    public ruc: string;
    public name: string;
}
```

trato de llamar en otra clase home.components.ts pero no me permite.

```
requesVO = ResquestVO; //como se llama en la clase home.components.ts
```

-error que sale  es (El tipo 'string' no se puede asignar al tipo 'string')// al utilizar en una función.

```
home.components.ts{
this.requestVO= request.name;
}
```

Estimados/as por favor su ayuda, recién empiezo con TypeScript, millón gracias.

Comment: Creo que deberías antes que nada estudiar un poquito sobre programación orientada a objetos. Te va a ser muy complicado usar typescript si no sabes crear y utilizar objetos. Si tienes la clase RequestVO, lo que tienes que hacer para poder usarla es instanciarla. Te dejo aquí la [documentación](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/classes.html) de TypeScript que tiene unos cuantos tutoriales básicos para que practiques.

Comment: @Benito-B Buen día, gracias por tu ayuda, voy a revisar la documentación.